# A variant of the definition of an ordinal number

Tags: ordinals, well-orders

A set is an ordinal if it is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$.
How do the transitive sets **linearly ordered** by $\in$ look like?
Are they again just ordinals by the regularity axiom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. More generally, the $\in$-ordering on any set is well-founded *(= every subset has a (possibly non-unique) minimal element; equivalently assuming AC, no descending chains exist)* by regularity, and the well-founded linear orders are exactly the well-orders.

Meanwhile, dropping *transitivity* results in a much weaker notion: for example, every singleton is linearly ordered by $\in$. Every set linearly ordered by $\in$ is "$\in$-isomorphic" to an ordinal, however.